# Test for a Bernoulli model with a single trial

Tags: hypothesis-testing, validation, bernoulli-distribution

I have a model that predicts Bernoulli probability parameters $p_i$ at $i\in[1..100]$ sites. To test this model, i can  only take one trial at each one of the sites, resulting in $\approx10$ successes.  Typical $p_i$ values are in the range $p_i\in[0.001, 0.2]$.

What is the best metric / test to evaluate the quality of my predictions for $p_i$.  I am looking for both formal and intuitive metrics.  Other than binary cross-entropy i cannot come up with anything, but it is super non-intuitive to me.

Comment: What is your loss function?

Comment: RE: What is your loss function\
@whuber

I don't have a loss function -- i have a physics-based model that predicts $p_i$ -- and i just want to judge how well it did

Comment: Your loss function is a quantitative expression of how you will judge differences.  We cannot give you a quantitative (that is, statistical or scientific) answer without that, nor can we provide objective opinions about what your loss ought to be, since that depends on your situation.

Comment: i am interested in a metric function, or a hypothesis test -- nothing is being optimized.  I think probability is $p_i$ and i have an experimental trial -- why do i need a loss?  As for a quantitate way to judge difference -- that is the core of my question, what's the best way ?

Comment: We are not communicating over the meaning of "loss function," then.  This is a term used in the foundations of statistical analysis.  Something indeed *is* being optimized: namely, the expected cost to you of making errors.  For instance, in your application you might need better accuracy at some sites compared to others; or maybe you have a model that suggests how the probability varies from one site to another (that's what logistic regression does); or maybe it costs you more to underestimate a probability than to overestimate one.  All of these are part of your loss function.